# PostgreSQL - Want SELECT/FROM/WHERE/IN query to return ALL values correlated to search terms. Even if duplicate

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, where-clause

By default, PostgreSQL returns just the distinct values for a SELECT/FROM/WHERE/IN query.
What do I need to do to get the number of results to match the number of input fields?

How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
SELECT ALL "letter" 
FROM "letters" 
WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2')
```

This will result in the following:
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'

This is what I'm looking for the result to be:
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B'

Comment: I hope you are not really storing numbers as strings

Comment: I'm not. The id column is an integer. Query above was stolen from a code snippet. Query seems to work with id's referenced as numbers or strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a JOIN, which will return one row for each matched parameter.

```
select l.letter
from letters l
  join (
     values (1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(2)
  ) as t(id) on t.id = l.id
```

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question (if you will), how do I retain the order? The result is AABBCD but I want to keep it ABCDAB. I tried using 
ORDER BY array_position(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,1,2], l.id) but that did not work